# How to monkey patch a single method when using jest.mock

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test a JS project which imports a third party library. I've been able to successfully mock the third-party library by doing this at the top of my test file:

```
jest.mock('third-party');
```

But now, I need to customize the mock implementation of a single method inside the third-party library. Let give diagram how the third-party library is structured because I think that's where I'm getting tripped up:

Third-Party Library Package

- Exports Constructor1

  - properties
  - tons of instance methods...
- Exports Constructor2

  - properties...
  - instance methodA
  - instance methodB `<- This is what I want to monkey patch.`

I want to monkey patch this because mocking this library currently gives me this in my test:

```
import { Constructor2 } from 'third-party';

jest.mock('third-party');

describe('Thing', () => {

   var instance 

   beforeEach(() => {
      instance = new Thing();
      instance.constuctor2instance = new Constructor2();
      instance.controls = instance.constuctor2instance.methodB(); 
     // methodB returns nothing because it's mocked. I want it to return a custom implementation. 
   });

   test('test 1', () => {
      // Fake test just for example
      expect(instance.constuctor2instance).toBeInstanceOf(Constructor2); // Success

      jest.spyOn(instance.controls, 'nestedFunction'); // Fails because instance.controls is undefined  
   });
});
```

So, how can I provide a custom implementation for `methodB` **without** having to define the implementation of the whole third party library or even the entire Constructor2...just one method?

**EDIT with solution from below from ** @Teneff

```
   jest.mock('third-party');

   const mockControls = {
     nestedFunction: jest.fn()
   };

    beforeEach(() => {
        Constructor2.prototype.controls.mockImplementation(() => mockControls);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Constructor2's prototype like this

```
const mockControls = {
  nestedFunction: jest.fn(),
};

Constructor2.prototype.methodB.mockImplementation(() => mockControls);
```

and you won't have to spy on it, you'd be able to make assertions like so:

```
expect(mockControls.nestedFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
```